# CSS Box Shadow-Animated Pixel Art Flickering

Tags: html, css, animation

Partly for funsies, and partly for a design idea I had, I'm trying to convert an animated gif into pure animated CSS.

It's very nearly working but I've hit a snag and am unsure what is causing my issue, or how I could fix it. I have an unfortunate suspicion that I've simply hit a limitation of the technology.

The gif I've been using for testing is this: https://us.v-cdn.net/5018289/uploads/editor/yj/lcdjneh1yoxv.gif

As for the actual CSS, I've been trying to implement the method here (animated box-shadow properties), as it seemed like the most feasible: https://codepen.io/andrewarchi/pen/OXEEgL

```
#ash::after {
  animation: ash-frames 0.4s steps(1) infinite;
}

@keyframes ash-frames {
    0% {box-shadow: 32px 8px #181818, 40px 8px #181818,...}
    ...
}
```

The animation seems fairly seamless in the given example, so I figured it was worth a try. Obvious differences: the gif I'm using has more frames *and* more pixels.

And just as a quick overview, my CSS (I am using vendor tags etc, this is just an example):

```
.pixel-art-3940::after {
    animation: pixel-art-3940-frames 1s steps(5, end) infinite;
}

@keyframes pixel-art-3940-frames {
    0% {box-shadow: 112px 68px rgba(77, 69, 64, 1),...}
    16.666666666666668% {box-shadow:115px 65px rgba(77, 69, 64, 1),...}
    ...
}
```

The animation does seem to be actually working, however there's an intense 'flickering' effect on the animation. See below:

[image: flickering animation]

I've tried the usual solutions to 'flickering transitions' in Chrome - such as setting `-webkit-backface-visibility` to `hidden` - but so far nothing has solved the issue.

As I said, I fear I've simply hit a limitation of the technology itself. Any ideas what the problem might be, and whether I can solve it?

EDIT: The full source code of this particular animation can be found in these two Gists. I opted for Gists because of the size of the CSS file.

- HTML: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ChrGriffin/2f1f221143e24d3e39cad8e7369bc167/raw/16ea77d21aa79cf9da52fc3477a6773af41130f2/image.html
- CSS: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ChrGriffin/7dcff0f119532ff37f68c01a8a22ecb5/raw/3e49d3dd0b7fa93aef6708750770d2616c53f682/image.css

Comment: The codepen shows a pokemon anim that appears fine, do you have your code for the thing you're asking about somewhere to reproduce what's shown?

Comment: @ChrisW. I added the full source to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Correct answer**

In the end, it was all due to the `animation-timing-function`. First param in `steps()` function is not the number of keyframes (or number of steps in the loop) but the number of steps rendered in between keyframes.

So changing it to `steps(1,end)` fixes it, as the browser no longer has to calculate intermediary frames (where it obviously fails due to the large number of `box-shadow` values - there's basically 1 value for each pixel - wicked technique, btw).

See it working: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/wnrxmapu/2/

---

**Previous answer:** (*partially incorrect, led to the correct one above - i left it as it might prove helpful to others debugging similar animations*):

Initially I thought your exporting tool was... simply wrong.

Why? Because increasing `animation-duration` from `1s` to `100s` produced [**this result**](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/wnrxmapu/).

The apparent conclusion is that your intermediary frames are bugged.

However, I tested each of them individually and, to my surprise, they rendered correctly.

Which leads to the conclusion that *the number of `box-shadow` calculations per keyframe is limited* and some sort of clustering algorithm is performed.

<strike>Which makes sense, since we're talking `box-shadow` here, which, in 99.999999999% of cases (basically **all** except yours) *does **not** have to be accurate*. It *should be* (and obviously is) approximated favoring rendering speed, for obvious reasons: we're talking user experience and "feel". Most users are non-technical and they simply expect smooth scrolling under any and all conditions.</strike>

I've come to the conclusion there must be a limit on the amount allowed calculations per keyframe after trying my best at optimizing your code, reducing it to less than half the initial size: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/wnrxmapu/1/

I wasn't able to find any material on pixel clustering techniques for `box-shadow` and I don't think much is available online - this should be classified information.

However, IMHO, other than bragging rights, I don't think your technique stands a chance in terms of rendering performance when compared to a gif or svg. Emphasis on *"IMHO"*. If you insist on getting this done, you might want to slice the image up and check if the limit on allowed calculation is per element or per page.

But I wouldn't keep my hopes too high. It is optimizations like the one your code has revealed that make CSS lightning fast. If it had to be accurate it wouldn't be so fast.

Comment: I saw this answer before you edited it and I have to say, I can't believe I didn't think of simply slowing the animation down to check what was happening. After slowing it down _and_ blowing up the size, I was _finally_ able to determine that the 'flickering' was actually the box-shadow transitioning from one 'frame' (CSS animation step) to another! The solve was actually ludicrously easy. Instead of defining a set number of steps for the animation, I simply made the rule `step-end` and it _all_ went away.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not sure how to approach this from a SO perspective. Your answer, _before_ the edit, led me to the solution - however, _after_ the edit, however informative and well-written it may be, doesn't actually contain the solution. But, you were the only one to answer at all! So I think I'll go ahead and say that if you can take some of the contextual info from your edit and add it to the original answer, that takes the win.

Comment: (except on review, you do include the major component of the original answer in your new answer - so uh, shrug?)

Comment: I'm surprised I didn't notice your `steps(5, end)`. For some reason I always assumed your animation was correct. It's `steps(1,end)`, of course. Ref improving the answer: this answer still contains the original one. I do say: I initially thought your steps were wrong. I also said both then and now how I got to that conclusion (blowing it up). And, if you change the timing function to `linear` and blow it up, you'll notice my answer holds water. Calculations are limited.

Comment: In the end, I'm glad I helped you along into getting it to work and I hope you'll find the conversion to hex useful. It did drop the char length from 1.9M to less than ~900k. Happy coding.

Comment: I remember falling for this issue before. The first parameter of `steps()` function is **NOT** the number of total keyframes, but the number of steps rendered **between keyframes**.

Comment: Yeah, that was clearly my mistake. No wonder I couldn't find an obvious problem.